# number the lines i load from a txt file

Tags: javascript, html

I load a txt file with only names through a load function into a div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#middiv").load("karten_deelnemers.txt");
});
```

How can I put a number in front of the first 60 names I load, then put some text and then number the rest of the file. Number 61 till 70 preferably in bold.

Comment: You can read the content to a hidden div, then get that content and manipulate it, like split on /n, and then show it in middiv

Comment: Hi Grumpy, do you have an example how that's going to work in code? I can load my txt file in an other div but I've got no clue how to get is from one div to an other and how to manipulate the content.

Comment: Create a <div id="hiddenDiv" style="width:1px; height:1px;"></div> $("#hiddenDiv").load("karten_deelnemers.txt").ready(function(){ let text=$('#hiddenDiv").html(); manipulate text and show in middiv });